# Refresh issue: Use pathname & array of urls to set next and previous links in React/Gatsby

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, window.location

I am using an array of links to paginate because I want them in a specific order. This all works fine, if I navigate to any of the features pages I can paginate through them; but if I refresh a page the Next href defaults to [0] or 'features/safety-training' and Prev ends up being undefined. I am assuming this is something to do with how useEffect works but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
   const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);
   const [next, setNext] = useState(null);
   const [prev, setPrev] = useState(null);

     let theArray =[
        "/features/safetytraining", 
        "/features/certificatetracking", 
        "/features/policies", 
        "/features/standard-operating-procedures", 
        "/features/competencies", 
        "/features/contractor-orientations", 
        "/features/worksite-screening", 
        "/features/inspections", 
        "/features/incident-reporting", 
        "/features/behavior-observations", 
        "/features/bulletins", 
        "/features/suggestions", 
        "/features/polls", 
        "/features/whistleblower"
    ]

    useEffect(() => {

        let pathname = window.location.pathname

        //Check the array for pathname

        let checkPosition = theArray.indexOf(pathname);

       //Set the position to pathname index

        setPosition(checkPosition)

    });

       //Update next/prev when position changes

    useEffect(() => {

        setNext(theArray[position +1])

        setPrev(theArray[position -1])

    }, [position]);
```

Here's the links:

```
            <>
            <button 
            style={{marginRight: '15px'}}>
                <Link to={prev}>Prev</Link>
                </button>

            <button>
                <Link to={next}>Next</Link>
                </button>
            </>
```

Comment: That's not really the issue, even when I am on a page in the middle of the list refreshing it causes the pathname not to be found in the array, as opposed to nagivating from anywhere on the website where it does recognize the pathname in the array. When I put the component on all the pages I will render the next/prev buttons conditionally so that it doesn't cause issues on the first or last page, but for now im testing on pages in the middle of the array so they should theoretically be working, even after I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need state or side effects (`useEffect`) for any of this:

```
// Pages don't change and don't depend on props or state,
// so let's define w/ `const` and extract from the
// component to avoid recreating on each render:
const pages = [
  "/features/safetytraining",
  "/features/certificatetracking",
  "/features/policies",
  "/features/standard-operating-procedures",
  "/features/competencies",
  "/features/contractor-orientations",
  "/features/worksite-screening",
  "/features/inspections",
  "/features/incident-reporting",
  "/features/behavior-observations",
  "/features/bulletins",
  "/features/suggestions",
  "/features/polls",
  "/features/whistleblower",
];

const Example = () => {
  // This is extraordinarily cheap to compute and will not
  // change without a re-render occurring, so we don't need
  // for it to be state:
  const position = typeof window === "undefined"
    ? 0
    : pages.indexOf(window.location.pathname);

  // Avoid using an invalid index position
  const prevPath = position <= 0 ? pages[pages.length] : pages[position - 1];
  const nextPath = position >= pages.length - 1 ? pages[0] : pages[position];

  return (
    <div>
      <button style={{ marginRight: "15px" }}>
        <Link to={prevPath}>Prev</Link>
      </button>

      <button>
        <Link to={nextPath}>Next</Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Your original code was creating a number of issues:

- Each time you call a setter function (e.g. `setPosition`) React queues a re-render of the component
- On the initial render, `position`, `prev`, and `next` were all `null`
- When doing the server-side render, `useEffect` is not called, so your links would be broken on the initial load
- Once the component was mounted client-side, both `useEffect` hooks would be called

  1. The first hook would call `setPosition`, prompting a re-render  where `position` was set (`prev` and `next` would still be `null`); since there is no dependency array, the first hook is called again, and `setPosition` is called again
  2. The second hook would be called again since `position` changed and call `setPrev` and `setNext`, prompting two more re-renders
  3. On the next render, `prev` would be set but `next` would not be
  4. On the next render, `next` would finally be set as expected

Comment: @alala_emily Awesome, be sure to accept it by hitting the checkmark to the left of the answer to let others know you no longer need answers here. Welcome to Stack Overflow!